# Use separate domain as forwarder of landing page for SEO

Tags: seo, google-search, landing-page

I have a website, which has a domain which is the company name. I also have a domain specificly for one of the services the company offers, plus a landing page created for that service.

From SEO perspective, would it be better to create a 301-redirect from that specific domain to the landing page, or to pull that landing page out of the company website, and make it a separate landing page / simple site?

So, set-up 1:

Specialservice.com is a 301 redirect to website.com/special-service

Or set-up 2:

Specialservice.com is a separate landing page, with links leading to website.com

In either case, there wouldn't be any duplicate content. There is just 1 page, and that's either it's own domain, or a page in a bigger website.

Which setup is better, and why?

EDIT: According to [closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36029/closetnoc), adding a redirect does nothing. But is a landing page worth the effort?

Comment: Adding more domain names that redirect to another does absolutely nothing. Otherwise, everyone would do it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally to increase the traffic, you can create the different domain and have totally different content but have links to your main website so that whenever a user clicks on any of the link it would go to an inner page on your mail website.

I've seen a ton of companies do the same